# How do I dynamically change color in C# to a hex value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I know how to set a control's BackColor dynamically in C#  to a named color with a statement such as Label1.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue; (  using System.Drawing;  )

But how do I convert a hex value into a System.Color , ie Label1.BackColor = "#B5C7DE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use the color translator as so:

```
var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF1133");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
string hexColor = "#B5C7DE";
Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Color.FromArgb(0xB5C7DE);
```

or, if you want to parse the string

```
private Color ParseColor(string s, Color defaultColor)
{
    try
    {
        ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter();
        Color c = (Color)(cc.ConvertFromString(s));

        if (c != null)
        {
            return c;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return defaultColor;
}
```

This function just returns the default if it can't parse s.  You could just let the exception through if you'd rather handle exceptions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Color.FromArgb method:

```
Label1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xB5C7DE);
```